# Delete or mark as deleted in large database cache?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I have a large database cache with a few million entries. The cache is rebuild two times a day. From time to time I'd like to remove some cache entries from the db. Or at least I'd like to prevent them to show up in some results.

Would you go and update an entry, eg `boolean deleted = true`, so that the result omits this entry? Or would you physically delete the row? Which is better with regards to performance, and of course due to the fact the cache is anyhow rebuild throughout the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DELETE and UPDATE has similar cost and similar speed in PostgreSQL (depends if you do update indexed or non indexed column), but after VACUUM a space used by deleted records can be reused, so database should not to blow too quickly. So usually DELETE is preferred - but it depends on more factors.

Comment: Eh? `UPDATE` is closer to `DELETE + INSERT`, it adds index update costs (unless it's a HOT update), and forces a whole new tuple write. `DELETE` just sets xmax. So there's a big cost difference.

Comment: I wrote "depends if you do update indexed or non indexed column"

Comment: @CraigRinger so you'd suggest to prefer a `DELETE`?

Comment: @PavelStehule True - and if it triggers a full_page_write there won't be any difference between xmax setting and an update (if there's free space in the page, e.g. low fillfactor). Still, an `UPDATE` is always at least as expensive, and very often much more expensive, and it demands a low fillfactor + un-indexed "deleted" col to perform OK.

Comment: @membersound Unless I had a reason to want to discover/list deleted rows or undelete rows, I'd absolutely use `DELETE`. If I wanted to be able to undo a delete easily I'd either use a side-table I inserted deleted rows into, or a deleted col + an update.